# CONCATENATE function inside SUM formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have set of numbers in D column of a sheet and I need to do SUM of set of cells and display it in different cell. My input SUM range may change each time.

For example, by using below formula, I am able to get the SUM from D3:D33 of sheet DayWise2019.

```
=SUM(DayWise2019!D3:D33)
```

Now, I am trying to use two cells to enter start and end cell number for the SUM function and trying to use concatenate to create the formula

Current sheet `D13` contains first cell of SUM range
Current sheet `D14` contains last cell of SUM range

I am using formula like below

```
=SUM(CONCATENATE("DayWise2019!","D",D13,":","D",D14))
```

But its not working. Getting error in value `"#VALUE"`. I checked the concatenate function alone and its working as expected.

`CONCATENATE("DayWise2019!","D",D13,":","D",D14)` will give `DayWise2019!D3:D33`

Is there anyway to resolve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use INDEX to set the start row (D13) and end row (D14) cells.

```
=SUM(index(DayWise2019!d:d, D13):index(DayWise2019!d:d, D14))
```

Avoid INDIRECT.

Comment: @JeepedThanks, thats working. Is there anyway I can make use value from a cell as sheet name instead of sheet DayWise2019 ?. I am trying to use different sheet for each month. so instead of hard coding the sheet name, trying to pull it from a cell

Comment: That isn't what was asked. However, you can do it with INDIRECT.

Comment: Thanks. I will check the indirect function reference